# Plotting Trajectories of 1-D and 2-D Dynamical Systems in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to know how I can plot the trajectories of Dynamical Systems using Python as shown below. Most of the examples I have come across that use Python don't plot the arrows.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Feel free to make edits to my question if it doesn't make sense.

[image: Phase Portraits]